# Table in mysql for pyramid_beaker session

Tags: mysql, pyramid, beaker

what columns are need to defined in mysql for storing session using pyramid_beaker?

```
session.type=ext:database
session.secret=someThingReallyReallySecret
session.cookie_expires=true
session.key=WhatEver
session.url=mysql://user:password@host/database
session.timeout=3000
session.lock_dir=%(here)s/var/lock
```

as it doesn't give any clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beaker will create the table itself if it hasn't been created already when it's first invoked.

You can see the code (and the columns it'll create) in [the ext/database.py source file](https://github.com/bbangert/beaker/blob/master/beaker/ext/database.py#L69)

```
cache = sa.Table(table_name, meta,
                 sa.Column('id', types.Integer, primary_key=True),
                 sa.Column('namespace', types.String(255), nullable=False),
                 sa.Column('accessed', types.DateTime, nullable=False),
                 sa.Column('created', types.DateTime, nullable=False),
                 sa.Column('data', types.PickleType, nullable=False),
                 sa.UniqueConstraint('namespace'),
                 schema=schema_name if schema_name else meta.schema
        ):
```

Comment: @user6813858 Using the ext:database backend requires using sqlalchemy. That's what it uses internally. See [line 29-31](https://github.com/bbangert/beaker/blob/master/beaker/ext/database.py#L29). It does however not affect anything else in your application, but it requires sqlalchemy to be installed.

Comment: is there any other way ?

Comment: @user6813858 If you want to use the existing ext:database, it uses SQLAlchemy internally. You don't have to pay any attention to that. If you want to use another DB abstraction layer, you'll have to reimplement the ext:database-driver (or find an existing one) for the abstraction layer you want to use. It's impossible to say without you actually describing what the problem is.

Comment: i am using mysql and i don't use any ORM.so only for this i don't want to install sqlalchemy.how i can do that?

Comment: Then you'll have to write your own version of ext:database that uses your abstraction layer instead of SQLa, or search around the web to find someone who has done that. ext:database uses SQLAlchemy, and if you don't want to install alchemy so that ext:database can work, you'll have to use something else.